# Historical letters of investiture

Tags: church-history, europe, missionary

Am wondering if "letters of investiture" (if that is the right term), from popes to early European missionaries, are available anywhere in print, or on the web? Am particularly interested in [Ansgar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansgar).